# WillChangeValue for keypath

Tags: objective-c, monomac

I have a class within a class with a property, e.g., Car.Engine.Name. I have implemented KVC and would like to send WillChangeValue for "Engine.Name" but it doesn't seem to register. Sending WillChangeValue for "Name" for Car.Name does work, on the other hand.

```
        Object target = _t;
        PropertyInfo info;
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++) {
            info = target.GetType ().GetProperty (keys[i]);
            if (i == keys.Length - 1) {
                WillChangeValue (nsKeyPath);  // <--- doesn't seem to work if there is a nontrival keypath
                info.SetValue (target, nsValue.ToObject (info.PropertyType), null);
                DidChangeValue (nsKeyPath);
            } else {

                target = info.GetValue (target, null);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, I needed to change WillChange for the top node, e.g., WillChangeValue("Engine"). In the implemented code, WillChangeValue(keys[0])